# Override single config value for specific environment

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In my default app.php file I have service providers and aliases defined like so:

Providers:

```
'providers' => array(
    'Illuminate\Session\CommandsServiceProvider',
    'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
    'SomeNamespace\Mail\MailServiceProvider',
    ...
),
```

Aliases:

```
'aliases' => array(
    'App'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\App',
    'Artisan'         => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan',
    'Mail'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail',
    ...
),
```

Say that I in my local environment only want to override single providers and aliases but keep the other default values. For instance I would like to change in my `config/local/app.php` the `MailServiceProvider` and `Mail` facade to refer to other classes for this environment only. Is this possible without having to define all providers and all aliases again (but with other values for MailServiceProvider and the Mail facade) in my local config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it would to use conditionally loading service providers.

You can do this on your `/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`file:

```
if ($this->app->environment('local')) {
    $this->app->register('App\Providers\LocalErrorHandlerServiceProvider');
} else {
    $this->app->register('App\Providers\ProductionErrorHandlerServiceProvider');
}
```

**Second but most effective in your case:**
You can create a service provider `LocalServiceProvider`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class LocalServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    protected $providers = [
        'Your\Local\ServiceProvider'
    ];
    protected $aliases = [
        'Local' => 'Your\Local\Facade'
    ];
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //register the service providers for local environment
        if ($this->app->isLocal() && !empty($this->providers)) {
            foreach ($this->providers as $provider) {
                $this->app->register($provider);
            }
            //register the alias
            if (!empty($this->aliases)) {
                foreach ($this->aliases as $alias => $facade) {
                    $this->app->alias($alias, $facade);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and add it on your `config/app.php`to load:

```
/*
 * Application Service Providers...
 */
App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\LocalServiceProvider::class,
```

This way, you can tell which service providers and aliases you want to load on your `LocalServiceProvider` class.